# How to add ESC button to the program in c++

Tags: c++

[This Is the Question here:][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAAvV.png

The program runs but the esc key doesn't work. I have to type in 27 to exit the program. Can somebody help me out with this how to function the esc key? Also the program has some errors I'm mentioning them below with bold text.

> **31  13  C:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Exam Practise\OOP Assignment 1 retake.cpp   [Warning] multi-character character constant
> [-Wmultichar]**
>
> **C:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Exam Practise\OOP Assignment 1 retake.cpp   In function 'int main()':**
>
> **31  13  C:\Users\muzam\OneDrive\Desktop\Exam Practise\OOP Assignment 1 retake.cpp   [Warning] overflow in implicit constant conversion
> [-Woverflow]**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
class tollbooth{
    private:
        unsigned int TotalCars;
        double TotalCash;
    public:
        tollbooth()
    {
        TotalCars = 0;
        TotalCash = 0;
    }
    void payingCar()
    {
        TotalCars += 1;
        TotalCash += 0.50;
    }
    void nopayCar()
    {
        TotalCars += 1;
    }
    void display()
    {
        cout<<"Total cars Passed: "<<TotalCars<<endl<<"Total Cash collected by cars: "<<"$"<<TotalCash<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    tollbooth t1;
    char ESC = '27';
    char ch;
    cout << "Enter 0 for each non-paying car" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 for each paying car" << endl;
    cout << "Press ESC to exit (Type 27 )" << endl;
    do{
        cin>>ch;
        if(ch == '0')
        {
            t1.nopayCar();
        }
        if(ch == '1')
        {
            t1.payingCar();
        }
    }
    while(ch != ESC);
    t1.display();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please check the formatting. Also, don't post links to images when you actually mean text. That said, `'27'` should probably be `27`. Many compilers actually warn you when you use things like that, so make sure you have warnings enabled. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The compiler actually _is_ warning about that, the question mentions a "multi-character character constant" warning

Answer (score 2):

**You can't (easily) read a typed ESC key from stdin.**

First, this line is wrong as pointed out in the comments:

```
char ESC = '27';
```

Should be:

```
char ESC = (char)27;
```

However, that doesn't matter. Because there's not a single console that I know of that will read in a pressed ESC key from stdin as if it was ordinary input. It's a special key, kind of like the shift and num lock keys on your keyboard.

You could technically embed a binary 27 byte in file and use redirection to get your code to read it, but you'll be hard pressed having it work interactively. Consider another way for the user to cleanly exit the program (e.g. type "9" to exit)